# Exception-proof HttpListener possible?

Tags: c#, exception, httplistener

Last few days I've been building a web server application in C# that uses HttpListener. I've learned quite a lot on the way, and still am. Currently I got it all working, setting headers here and there depending on certain situations.

In most cases things are working fine, however at times a exception error is thrown. This happens on a few occasions. Most if not all of them is closing a connection before all data is send. Then the error occurs. But some of them are really caused by browsers as far as I can tell.

Like let's take Chrome. Whenever I go to a MP3 file directly, it sends 2 GET requests. And one of them is causing the error, the other is working and receiving part of the content. After this, I can listen the MP3 and there are no issues. Streaming works.
But back to the request that gives me the error, there is nothing in the headers that I could use in my code to not output data, like I do already with HEAD requests. So I'm quite puzzled here.

IE also has this problem with both opening MP3 files directly, and streaming via HTML5 audio tag. It also varies from time to time. Sometimes I open the page, and only 2 requests are made. The HTML page, and the MP3. No error there. Sometimes tho, there are 3 requests. It connects to the MP3 twice. Now sometimes one of those connections is being aborted straight after I open the page, and sometimes 2 requests to the MP3 file, doesn't even accept data. In both request headers, they want end of the file. So bytes: 123-123/124.
I've also tested it on w3school's audio element. IE also makes twice connections there, one aborted, other loading the MP3 file.

So my question is, is it possible to make the web server exception/error-proof, or maybe better question, is it bad that these exceptions are thrown? Or do you perhaps know how to fix these errors?

The error I'm getting is: I/O Operation has been aborted by either a thread exit or an application request.

The way I write to the client is:

```
            using (Stream Output = _CResponse.OutputStream)
            {
                Output.Write(_FileOutput, rangeBegin, rangeLength);
            }
```

I am not sure if there's another (better) way. This is what I came across in many topics, tutorials and pages while researching.

About headers: Default headers: Content Length, Content Type, Status Code. In some cases, like MP3 files and video's, I add a Accept-Ranges: Bytes header. In case the request header has Range in it, I add Content-Range header, and PartialContent status code.

Comment: What is the difference in those multiple requests by different browsers? Have you used WireShark or similar?

Comment: No, I've used Inspect Element of the browsers to see the headers, and sometimes I read out Request.Headers and write the results in Console. The difference in headers, between the successful and unsuccessful connection depends on browsers. Chrome barely has any changes in the header, for the successful connection it shows Accept: * . * , and Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0. For the unsuccessful connection he uses the headers Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp, * / * ;q=0.8 and Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch. Those are the only differences for Chrome.

Comment: As for IE, there is no difference what so ever, just abort one of the 2 connections straight away. Sometimes make 2 connections where he wants 0 bytes of the end of the file. I've fixed this already by checking if the rangeLength is actually above 0.

Comment: Post the exception ToString.

Comment: @usr System.Net.HttpListenerException<0x80004005> I/O Operation has been aborted by either a thread exit or an application request. - That is what the console shows.

Comment: It's not the ToString output. A lot of information is missing. Question is unanswerable as it stands. Capture the full ToString and post it here.

Comment: @usr Alright. System.Net.HttpListenerException <0x80004005>: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at ConsoleApplication.ClientHandler.SendData() in Client.cs:line179 at ConsoleApplication2.ClientHandler..ctor(HttpListenerContext Client, Server IServer) in Client.cs:line 54 at HandleClient(HttpListenerContext context) in Server.cs:line 109 - Hopefully this is the information you requested.

Comment: Thanks. What do you find surprising? The aborted requests or that your server fails because of them?

Comment: @usr Both, in a way. The aborted requests are unusual, but I found an explaination for some of the browsers behavior, or so I think. That my server gives an exception, well, it's clear why it happens. I just don't like it happening, and was wondering if there was a way to fix it. If it's not, then I was wondering if these exceptions are alright to let it happen?

Comment: From the server's point of view any client can disconnect at any time. This is part of the normal operation of a server. Detect this specific case, log it and swallow the exception (because it has been handled). It's not a server bug.

Comment: I may have an explanation why IE/Chrome is making more requests than needed, and quickly abort them. I just came across another bug, this time with Mozilla. Where the audio file was not fully loaded. Just a part of it, and that's because I was setting the limit of package-sizes through Content Range. Mozilla doesn't support that. Anyway, I was searching for this bug, and came across some old bug reports: [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=502894) Here it's being explained that multiple requests are done to determine how big the file is. I believe that's what IE/Chrome does.

Comment: @usr: Alright thanks. That's all I wanted to know. I just wasn't sure if they are okay or not. Also read my post above, the multiple requests are there to read out certain data, like size and time. After they collected the data, the request is being aborted. At least this was the case of Mozilla in 2009. Seems not anymore tho, but it still happening in Chrome and IE for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the server's point of view any client can disconnect at any time. This is part of the normal operation of a server. Detect this specific case, log it and swallow the exception (because it has been handled). It's not a server bug.